# ¿Por qué no me muestra el primer registro?

Tags: php, mysql, while

Al final hago un recorrido con un for

```
      <label for="nombre">Nombre personal</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>">
      <label for="empresa">Empresa</label>
       <select multiple="multiple" name="id_empresa[]" id="id_empresa" class="notItemOne">
        <?php
        include "../ConexionALOGIN.php";
      $query_empresa = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM t_empresas");
      $result_empresa = mysqli_num_rows($query_empresa);

        
           while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_empresa)){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $data["idt_empresas"]; ?>"><?php echo $data["nombreE"]; ?></option>
```

Comment: Estás seguro que pusiste tu código completo?

Comment: No  amigo, solo que está largo y no pude subirlo todo

Comment: Esta línea ` $result_empresa = mysqli_num_rows($query_empresa            if($result_empresa > 0){ ` es imposible que esté correcta. Intenta poner código funcional por favor, si pones código a trozos es imposible saber donde está el problema. Además, no es necesario que cierres y abras tantas veces el tag <?php, puedes poner un `echo "<option value=".$data['idt_empresas'].">".$data["nombreE"]."</option>";` en vez de abrir y cerrar 3 tags php.

Comment: Procura incluir entonces, el código relevante. No las 800 líneas del php sino la parte que crees que es relevante para que los demás sepamos qué intentas hacer. Es que el código está en un estado raro, con un if ahí como enredado y unos paréntesis sin cerrar. Revisa y edita, por favor :)

Comment: Lo agregue un poco más estructurado

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema, qué esperas del código y qué hace actualmente?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con select multiple en php y mysql, hago una consulta a la base, me regresa los datos, sin embargo el puntero siempre se inicia en el segundo registro, por el momento tengo solo 3 registros, y en el select multiple solo me aparecen 2, lo que quiero es que me aparezcan los 3.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit], explica en la pregunta el problema y luego pon el código que estás usando. Explica también por qué haces dos veces la misma consulta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr en sí?